# What does this TypeScript declaration mean?

Tags: typescript

What does this declaration mean?

```
_YearlyApyStats({ vaultId }: { vaultId: VaultEntity['id'] }) {
```

Comment: `_YearlyApyStats` seems to be a function call, but it's impossible to say what it does without further context. You should add the whole code, or at least all the relevant parts of it, and give some context as well.

Comment: I don't think this should get downvotes or be closed. IMHO it is a good question, because the parts of the syntax can be confusing. And it has enough details to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a function definition with one parameter.

The parameter is of type `{ vaultId: VaultEntity['id'] }`, i.e. an object with one property called `vaultId` and the type of this property is `VaultEntity['id']`, which just means: use the type of the property `id` from the `VaultEntity` type.

for example, if we have

```js
interface VaultEntity {
  id: string;
}
const foo: VaultEntity['id];
```

then the type of `foo` is `string`

The part `{ vaultId }` just uses the spread feature to get the `vaultId` property from the passed parameter.
i.e. it is the same as:

```js
function _YearlyApyStats(param: { vaultId: VaultEntity['id'] }) {
  const vaultId = param.vaultId;
}
```